# java jdbc connection - result set output problems

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, resultset

I am currently trying to implement a jdbc connection that returns all the data in a table when i "search" for anything that matches the input with '%input%'.

eg `ResultSet rs4 = stm4.executeQuery("select imageTime from image_data where imageName like '%" + value3 + "%' or imageTime like '%" + value3 + "%' or imageLocation like '" + value3 + "'" );`

i am trying to return ALL the rows in the result set as search results.
but if i have Resultset.next commanded when there is no more rows to go to it
causes the following results sets to all null,....

if anything id love a method to output the entire result set, thanks.

EDIT
editing the question: to be more direct; i need a way to get every piece of data from each row in each containing column of the result set. so i can output it.
This is my attempt of this below.

rs4 = a Resultset as declared below.

here is my code;

```
if(name_time_location == 1)
        {                
            String value3=searchInput.getText();//Sets the search Input as value3


            // selecting the cominbation from table, that match input options                               
            try{
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:blah blah");

                // Query the database for the correct username and passord                    
                Statement stm3 = con.createStatement();  
                Statement stm4 = con.createStatement();
                Statement stm5 = con.createStatement();


                //queries database for password from input username 
                ResultSet rs3 = stm3.executeQuery("select imageName from image_data    where imageName like '%" + value3 + "%' or imageTime like '%" + value3 + "%' or imageLocation like '" + value3 + "'" );
                //ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs3.getMetaData();
                //stm3.setFetchSize(5);
                //rs3.last();
                //int numberOfRows = rs3.getRow();


                //String[] resultList; 
                //resultList = new String[numberOfRows];
                // Fetch each row from the result set
                rs3.beforeFirst();
                while(rs3.next())
                {
                    imageSearchResult1 = rs3.getString(1); 
                    rs3.next();
                    imageSearchResult11 = rs4.getString(1);
                    rs3.next();
                    imageSearchResult12 = rs4.getString(1);
                    rs3.next();
                    imageSearchResult13 = rs4.getString(1);
                    rs3.next();
                    imageSearchResult14 = rs4.getString(1); 
                }rs3.close();

            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                    //System.out.println("Exception: " + e + "");
            }

            System.out.println("Search Results: \nName: " + imageSearchResult1 + "         Time stamp: " + imageSearchResult2 + "   Location: " + imageSearchResult3 + "\n" +
                    "Name: " + imageSearchResult11 + "   Time stamp: " + imageSearchResult21 + "   Location: " + imageSearchResult31 + "\n" + 
                    "Name: " + imageSearchResult12 + "   Time stamp: " + imageSearchResult22 + "   Location: " + imageSearchResult32 + "\n" +
                    "Name: " + imageSearchResult13 + "   Time stamp: " + imageSearchResult23 + "   Location: " + imageSearchResult33 + "\n" +
                    "Name: " + imageSearchResult14 + "   Time stamp: " + imageSearchResult24 + "   Location: " + imageSearchResult34 + "\n" );
```

Comment: Are you getting some exception or something? Your problem is not clear enough.

Comment: May be there is a problem with sql query means no record found to the corresponding where clause

Comment: Also, can you edit the question to so that we can know what rs4 is? Since you are selecting only imagelocation in stm5, using rs5.getString(2) will throw exception.

Comment: editing the question: to be more direct; i need a way to get every row of every column of the result set. so i can output it.

Comment: **DO NOT BUILD SQL STATEMENTS LIKE THIS!** (sorry for shouting). You're building a [SQL Injection Vulnerability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (obligatory [XKCD link](http://xkcd.com/327/)).

Comment: my sql statement works perfectly, through all the testing i have done.
the only issue is returning the results....

Comment: "*every row of every column*" does not make any sense. Columns don't have rows. I think you are confusing some concepts here.

Comment: @user1405235: then you haven't tested it enough. Try the input `o'neill`.

Comment: my issue was solved, thanks for the help and sorry about the in-clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can achieve the same thing by modifying the query and instead of creating 3 queries, get the 3 values in the same query as:

```
select imageName,imageLocation,imageTime from .....
```

Then use this query to generate the ResultSet and get the three values as `rs.getType(1),rs.getType(2),rs.getType(3)`.

In the same `while(rs.next())` loop, you can print the data that you want to print.

Comment: this would successfully get me the entire row, but how would i get the remaining rows?
rs.next() causes nulls?

Comment: Try by removing `rs.beforeFirst()`. Also confirm that the query returns some result by executing it directly on DB.

Comment: yeah i did that haha, it worked perfectly. It was a small syntax error. that new format helped alot thanks!
but now it seems the:

ResultSet rs4 = stm4.executeQuery("select imageTime from image_data where imageName like '%" + value3 + "%' or imageTime like '%" + value3 + "%' or imageLocation like '" + value3 + "'" );

statement can only have one "or" the second "or" is ignored.